# Fill blank value in Excel

Tags: excel

Need help in Excel for the following problem

```
ColA    ColB
A1  B1
A2  B2
A3  B3
A4  
A5  B5
A6  A6
A6  
A6
```

if Column B is blank, I need to copy the value of ColA into ColB. But if the value is already present, then no action is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is it with formula or Vba?

A formula like should be ok (you copy/paste this formula to every cells in your Col)

```
=IF(B1="",A1,B1)
```

Comment: Great ! Don't forget to put +1 and answered questions, to help other users if they have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

In column C enter the following formula:

```
=IF(B1="", A1, B1)
```

Copy this formula down column C.  Then, assuming it looks right, you may delete the current column B, leaving the new column to become the new column B.

It is important to note that this formula won't work if directly entered into column B.  In that case, Excel would complain about a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the entire column B used range and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open find and replace then insert select

find " " (leave blank)

replace  `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),,-1,1)`

Which looks like:

[image: Find and replace]

**Result:**

This, `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())`, refers to the cell itelf, and `-1` column offset argument refers to column to left.

[image: Result]

You can then do copy paste as values to convert formulas to hard coded values.